# Pass Internet Address (URL) through HTTP connection or SSL connection

Tags: web-services, url, service, mule

In MULE CE 3.3.0, I want to control URLs requests by HTTP connection, SSL connection or any other connections. 
Actually I have a Internet URL (www.web-mail.com) that all the clients for seeing this web-mail, enter this address (www.web-mail.com) in their browser.
Now I want to put my **MULE server (ESB)** between my web-mail server and clients then **transfer Client's request (www.web-mail.com) through MULE server (ESB) toward Web-mail server**. In each requests and calls (www.web-mail.com) from client to server I want to use MULE for logging, during this process I don't need to any contents. Just number of calling www.web-mail.com is important for me, that I want to count them by mule.

[image]

How can I do this issue? Is it possible?How????

Comment: Do you need to support all HTTP verbs or just GET? Do you need to carry forward sub-paths and query parameters to `web-mail.com` or just hit `/`?

Comment: @David Dossot I don't want to bother www.web-mail.com, I just want to hit www.web-mail.com calls

Comment: Mmmh sorry I don't get it, I thought you wanted to proxy calls to `web-mail.com`, while keeping track of the hit count.

Answer (score 0):

For simple things, you can use:

Proxy pattern: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Proxy+Pattern

Bridge pattern: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Bridge+Pattern

Comment: No, they were proposed as alternatives.